# Laravel как выбрать количество записей из дргуой таблицы

Tags: php, sql, laravel, api, eloquent

Есть две таблицы, к примеру:

Articles - id, title, body

Likes - id, user_id, user_ip, article_id

Как мне выбрать все записи из таблицы Articles вместе с количеством лайков, чтобы в результате запроса были поля: id, title, body, likes_count

я пробовал что-то типо этого:

```
 $articles = Article::where('unique_name', $request->unique_name)
            ->with(['category', 'status'])
            ->join('likes', 'articles.id', '=', 'likes.article_id')
            ->select('articles.*', 'COUNT(likes.*) AS likes_count')
            ->get();
```

и некоторые другие варианты пробовал, но ничего не работает. Help pls!

Comment: Читайте документацию: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models. И не городите через join всякого, прописывайте нормально отношения...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а что вы против join'ов имеете? Запросы с ними работают на порядок быстрее "нормальных отношений", и их стоит применять там, где скорость загрузки имеет значение

Comment: `->select(['articles.*', DB::raw('COUNT(likes.article_id) AS likes_count')])`

Comment: @InDevX Потому что иначе придется костылить. И автор уже использует и так отношения. Плюс "Laravel" и "быстрее" – это несовместимые понятия. Хочется нормально – нужно переходить хотя бы на Symfony или слезать уже наконец-то с PHP)))

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Может юзать sql это тоже костыль? Про "быстрее" вообще бред... Если тупо используете "нормальные отношения" то тогда бред понятен, в противном же случае не понятно, как и про php, собственно, весьма странные "наезды", без чего-то конкретного

Comment: @InDevX Не переходите в крайности. И посмотрите бенчмарки, будет всё понятно. Или использовать по полной связи, или как можно меньше тогда уж. И опять же, смотрите дебаг запросов, часто в отношениях запросы достаточно хорошо оптимизированы. А JOIN сам по себе тоже медленный, вложенные запросы быстрее, например. Разбирайтесь в предметной области сначала.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar не смешите) Судя по таким вот ответам вы от каких-то блогов на том же laravel не далеко убежали. И в крайности (будем использовать только одно?) тут вы переходите... А мне бенчмарки не нужны, у меня проект с 4кк онлайна, и так прекрасно всё вижу

Comment: @InDevX Смешно. Пожалуй, прекращу, бессмысленно. Советую всё же посмотреть на другие языки и фреймворки, не нужно завязывать себе глаза)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Мне PHP, Go и node.js хватает) Смешно, действительно. Потому что билдер строит 1 запрос, а просто модель с hasMany 2, и разница в 2 раза практически, для 10к записей, через ray смотрел. И как не строй эту связь, она не будет быстрей.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вашего проекта нет 4кк онлайна - используйте отношения.

```
class Article extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }
}

...

$articles = Article::where('unique_name', $request->unique_name)
        ->with(['category', 'status', 'likes'])->get();

foreach($articles as $article) {
    // ...
    $article->likes->count();
}
```

Comment: Дело в том что в моем проекте лайки могут ставить и не авторизированные пользователи (гости), которых нет в базе данных. Если лайк поставит гость то я записываю в таблицу с лайками ip адрес этого гостя, который никак не связывается с другими таблицами. Поэтому для вашей схемы мне бы пришлось создавать отдельную таблицу guests где я хранил бы ip адреса, и с ней уже связывать лайки гостей и делать что-то вроде этого `->with['userLikes', 'guestLikes']` либо как-то мудрить с таблицей users и в неё записывать ip адреса гостей. Мне легче использовать select который предложил @InDevX